# Remove the unnecessary text about "on most sites" from the login credentials Help Center page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login, help-center

The Help Center page [How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) says that, "on [most sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)", you can follow a certain procedure to add a new login to your account (with screenshots) – implying that on the others, you need to use a different procedure.

But those CSS updates already finished being applied to all SE sites quite a while ago – except Area 51, which will never be updated (and which is almost no one's sole site anyway).

Can we get the extra text gone, and leave it only for Area 51 or even nowhere at all?

Comment: Also doesn't work on stackexchange.com which isn't really a Q&A site. :)

Comment: Related MSO post about other updates needed for this Help Center page: [Update Help Center page about login credentials](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291685/1478931)

Comment: A summary: From what I can tell from the "[Your logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current)" page (and based on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/335251)), the whole section mentioning OpenID in the first paragraph is no longer accurate; the only options now are adding an SE username/password combo, Google login, or Facebook login. The "Edit Profile and Settings" tab has been renamed to "Settings", and "My Logins" in the settings sidebar has become "Your logins". (And of course, the screenshot needs to be updated as well – or simply removed.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've overhauled the page to remove the unnecessary text and also update the screenshots and login provider options.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention - apologies for the delay in improving the page!

Comment: This took 6-8 time units to fix... illuminati confirmed? ;)